# Quarter turns according to coordinate axes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I'm trying to implement quarter turn style arguments in TikZ, in such a way that

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (2cm,1cm) coordinate (A);
\draw[blue,->]  (A) [northwestqturn=3cm];
\draw[green,->]  (A) [northeastqturn=3cm];
\draw[red,->]  (A) [southwestqturn=3cm];
\draw[yellow,->]  (A) [southeastqturn=3cm];
\draw (A) node {$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

is equivalent to

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (2cm,1cm) coordinate (A);
\draw[blue,->]  (A)   arc[start angle=0, delta angle=90, radius=3cm];
\draw[green,->]  (A) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=(-90), radius=3cm];
\draw[red,->]  (A) arc[start angle=0, delta angle=(-90), radius=3cm];
\draw[yellow,->]  (A)   arc[start angle=180, delta angle=90, radius=3cm];
\draw (A) node {$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Below is my failed attempt. I feel that it was a near miss and a minor typo is probably all that's keeping my code from working. Any help appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\tikzset{
  nwchord/.style args={#1}{
    /utils/exec=%
   radius=#1, start angle=0, delta angle=90},
  northwestqturn/.style={insert path={arc[nwchord={#1}]}},
 nwchord r/.initial=,
  nwchord do/.style={nwchord={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/nwchord r}}},
}

\tikzset{
  swchord/.style args={#1}{
    /utils/exec=%
  radius=#1, start angle=270, delta angle=(-90)},
  southwestqturn/.style={insert path={arc[swchord={#1}]}},
  swchord r/.initial=,
  swchord do/.style={swchord={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/swchord r}}},
}

\tikzset{
  sechord/.style args={#1}{
    /utils/exec=%
  radius=#1, start angle=180, delta angle=90},
  southeastqturn/.style={insert path={arc[sechord={#1}]}},
  sechord r/.initial=,
  sechord do/.style={sechord={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sechord r}}},
}

\tikzset{
  nechord/.style args={#1}{
    /utils/exec=%
   radius=#1, start angle=180, delta angle=(-90)},
  northeastqturn/.style={insert path={arc[nechord={#1}]}},
  nechord r/.initial=,
  nechord do/.style={nechord={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/nechord r}}},
}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (2cm,1cm) coordinate (A);
\draw[blue,->]  (A) [northwestqturn=3cm];
\draw[green,->]  (A) [northeastqturn=3cm];
\draw[red,->]  (A) [southwestqturn=3cm];
\draw[yellow,->]  (A) [southeastqturn=3cm];
\draw (A) node {$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (2cm,1cm) coordinate (A);
\draw[blue,->]  (A)   arc[start angle=0, delta angle=90, radius=3cm];
\draw[green,->]  (A) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=(-90), radius=3cm];
\draw[red,->]  (A) arc[start angle=0, delta angle=(-90), radius=3cm];
\draw[yellow,->]  (A)   arc[start angle=180, delta angle=90, radius=3cm];
\draw (A) node {$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the typo is the first two lines of each style for example `nwchord/.style={radius=#1, start angle=0, delta angle=90},` draws.

Comment: @percusse draws and produces the expected output. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it (unless someone else explains further and says what the correct syntax with `/utils/exec` and `style args` should have been

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `/utils/exec` is meant to run a particular code through the keys to do auxiliary operations in TeX. It doesn't run keys, doesn't execute key code (unless you use pgfkeys commands). So here it has nothing to do with the purpose.

`/.style args` is a handler for creating custom keys with particular syntax such as `mykey/.style args={I want an argument#1and#2with#3}` then you can call this key with

```
mykey= I want an argument 3cm and green with onion
```

then `#1` will be `3cm` and so on.

In your case you are defining a style args but the argument is going to be a simple argument meaning there is no extra pattern hence a `/.style` would be sufficient.

And you can simplify things a bit

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  qturn/.style args ={#1with#2}{insert path={arc[#1=#2]}},
  ne/.style={radius=#1, start angle=180, delta angle=-90},
  nw/.style={radius=#1, start angle=0,   delta angle=90},
  se/.style={radius=#1, start angle=180, delta angle=90},
  sw/.style={radius=#1, start angle=0,   delta angle=(-90)},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (2cm,1cm) coordinate (A);
\draw[blue,->]   (A) [qturn= ne with 3cm];
\draw[green,->]  (A) [qturn= nw with 3cm];
\draw[red,->]    (A) [qturn= se with 3cm];
\draw[yellow,->] (A) [qturn= sw with 3cm];
\draw (A) node {$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a question about the `arc[#1=#2]` part in your code. Are those the same `#1` and `#2` from `{#1with#2}` ?

Comment: @user40960 Yes, the first part defines the custom input pattern and the second part defines how they are used. So in effect it becomes `ne=3cm` for example.